# Material-ui svg-icons inside another element doesnt align to the center

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the material ui library in my react project, and I have come across a strange issue, when I try to use svg icons inside a button-icon, the icom doesn't align to the center.

for example:

```
<ListItem key={product.id}
          primaryText={product.title}
          leftAvatar={<Avatar src={product.img}/>}
          rightIcon={<IconButton><RemoveIcon/></IconButton>}/>
```

for this code I will get the following result:
[image: A]

And for this code:

```
<ListItem key={product.id}
          primaryText={product.title}
          leftAvatar={<Avatar src={product.img}/>}
          rightIcon={<RemoveIcon/>}/>
```

I will get the following result : [image]

My question is, how do i get to the result of my second example, but that the icon will we inside another element?

Comment: why do you want an `IconButton` there?

Comment: because I want a button with an icon, can you think of another way to do this?

Comment: The `Listitem` component has its own ripple effect across the whole line. Usually you wouldn't put a button in there (at least in my opinion). Are u gonna have a specific click event in that avatar?

Comment: Well, what i have in mind is that when you click on the X button, the item will just be removed from the cart, that is what the button is for

Comment: I'd suggest you not to use the `ListItem` in this case, unless you really want that ripple effect across the line. If you just use an `Paper`, for example, you would have the ripple effect from the button.. isnt that enough?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of late but I recently had the same issue and solved it by wrapping the IconButton component in a custom component and extending the css. You may have to change some other CSS to make it align perfectly but this worked for my use case.

```js
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';

const CustomIconButton = (props) => {
    const { style } = props;
    const additionalStyles = {
        marginTop: '0'
    };
    return(
        <IconButton {...props } style={{ ...style, ...additionalStyles }} iconStyle={{ fontSize: '20px' }}/>
    );
};

CustomIconButton.PropTypes = {
    // listed all the props that IconButton requires (check docs)
};

export default PPIconButton;
```

This is what a simplified usage of this custom IconButton looks like:

```js
const deleteIconButton = (deleteFunc) => {
  return <CustomIconButton
      touch={true}
      tooltip="Delete"
      tooltipPosition="top-right"
      onTouchTap={deleteFeed}
      iconClassName="fa fa-trash"
      />;
};

class MyList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <List>
            <ListItem value={ i } primaryText="My List Item" rightIcon={ deleteIconButton(() => this.props.deleteFeed(i) } />
          ) }
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the styles down to the inner element worked for me:

```
return <SvgIcon style={this.props.style} />
```

Answer (score -1):

check this code, working fine for me

```
import React from 'react';
import List from 'material-ui/List';
import ListItem from 'material-ui/List/ListItem';

import Delete from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/delete';


const MenuExampleIcons = () => (
  <div>
    <List style={{width:"300px"}}>
      <ListItem primaryText="New Config" leftIcon={<Delete />} />
      <ListItem primaryText="New Config" rightIcon={<Delete />} />
    </List>
  </div>
);

export default MenuExampleIcons;
```

Comment: Yeah, it does work, and i tried that, but with this way, it just an icon, and i want it to be a button